# Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows

Tags: r, string, split, r-faq

I have a data frame, like so:

```
data.frame(director = c("Aaron Blaise,Bob Walker", "Akira Kurosawa", 
                        "Alan J. Pakula", "Alan Parker", "Alejandro Amenabar", "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu", 
                        "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu,Benicio Del Toro", "Alejandro González Iñárritu", 
                        "Alex Proyas", "Alexander Hall", "Alfonso Cuaron", "Alfred Hitchcock", 
                        "Anatole Litvak", "Andrew Adamson,Marilyn Fox", "Andrew Dominik", 
                        "Andrew Stanton", "Andrew Stanton,Lee Unkrich", "Angelina Jolie,John Stevenson", 
                        "Anne Fontaine", "Anthony Harvey"), AB = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'))
```

As you can see, some entries in the `director` column are multiple names separated by commas. I would like to split these entries up into separate rows while maintaining the values of the other column. As an example, the first row in the data frame above should be split into two rows, with a single name each in the `director` column and 'A' in the `AB` column.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious:  Is this data you should be posting on the interwebs?

Comment: They "weren't all B movies".  Seems innocuous enough.

Comment: All these people are Academy Award nominees, which I hardly think is a secret =)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This old question frequently is being used as dupe target (tagged with `r-faq`). As of today, it has been answered three times offering 6 different approaches but **is lacking a benchmark** as guidance which of the approaches is the fastest<sup>1</sup>.

The benchmarked solutions include

- [Matthew Lundberg's base R approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13773900/3817004) but modified according to [Rich Scriven's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows#comment71864689_13773900),
- [Jaap's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514711/3817004) two `data.table` methods and two `dplyr` / `tidyr` approaches,
- [Ananda's `splitstackshape`solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291428/3817004),
- and two additional variants  of Jaap's `data.table` methods.

Overall 8 different methods were benchmarked on 6 different sizes of data frames using the `microbenchmark` package (see code below).

The sample data given by the OP consists only of 20 rows. To create larger data frames, these 20 rows are simply repeated 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000 times which give problem sizes of up to 2 million rows.

#### Benchmark results

[image]

The benchmark results show that for sufficiently large data frames all `data.table` methods are faster than any other method. For data frames with more than about 5000 rows, Jaap's `data.table` method 2 and the variant `DT3` are the fastest, magnitudes faster than the slowest methods.

Remarkably, the timings of the two `tidyverse` methods and the `splistackshape` solution are so similar that it's difficult to distiguish the curves in the chart. They are the slowest of the benchmarked methods across all data frame sizes.

For smaller data frames, Matt's base R solution and `data.table` method 4 seem to have less overhead than the other methods.

#### Code

```
director <- 
  c("Aaron Blaise,Bob Walker", "Akira Kurosawa", "Alan J. Pakula", 
    "Alan Parker", "Alejandro Amenabar", "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu", 
    "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu,Benicio Del Toro", "Alejandro González Iñárritu", 
    "Alex Proyas", "Alexander Hall", "Alfonso Cuaron", "Alfred Hitchcock", 
    "Anatole Litvak", "Andrew Adamson,Marilyn Fox", "Andrew Dominik", 
    "Andrew Stanton", "Andrew Stanton,Lee Unkrich", "Angelina Jolie,John Stevenson", 
    "Anne Fontaine", "Anthony Harvey")
AB <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
        "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A")

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
```

#### Define function for benchmark runs of problem size `n`

```
run_mb <- function(n) {
  # compute number of benchmark runs depending on problem size `n`
  mb_times <- scales::squish(10000L / n , c(3L, 100L)) 
  cat(n, " ", mb_times, "\n")
  # create data
  DF <- data.frame(director = rep(director, n), AB = rep(AB, n))
  DT <- as.data.table(DF)
  # start benchmarks
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    matt_mod = {
      s <- strsplit(as.character(DF$director), ',')
      data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(DF$AB, lengths(s)))},
    jaap_DT1 = {
      DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))), by = AB
         ][!is.na(director)]},
    jaap_DT2 = {
      DT[, strsplit(as.character(director), ",", fixed=TRUE), 
         by = .(AB, director)][,.(director = V1, AB)]},
    jaap_dplyr = {
      DF %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(director = strsplit(as.character(director), ",")) %>%
        tidyr::unnest(director)},
    jaap_tidyr = {
      tidyr::separate_rows(DF, director, sep = ",")},
    cSplit = {
      splitstackshape::cSplit(DF, "director", ",", direction = "long")},
    DT3 = {
      DT[, strsplit(as.character(director), ",", fixed=TRUE),
         by = .(AB, director)][, director := NULL][
           , setnames(.SD, "V1", "director")]},
    DT4 = {
      DT[, .(director = unlist(strsplit(as.character(director), ",", fixed = TRUE))), 
         by = .(AB)]},
    times = mb_times
  )
}
```

#### Run benchmark for different problem sizes

```
# define vector of problem sizes
n_rep <- 10L^(0:5)
# run benchmark for different problem sizes
mb <- lapply(n_rep, run_mb)
```

#### Prepare data for plotting

```
mbl <- rbindlist(mb, idcol = "N")
mbl[, n_row := NROW(director) * n_rep[N]]
mba <- mbl[, .(median_time = median(time), N = .N), by = .(n_row, expr)]
mba[, expr := forcats::fct_reorder(expr, -median_time)]
```

#### Create chart

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mba, aes(n_row, median_time*1e-6, group = expr, colour = expr)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(se = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = NROW(director) * n_rep) + scale_y_log10() + 
  xlab("number of rows") + ylab("median of execution time [ms]") +
  ggtitle("microbenchmark results") + theme_bw()
```

#### Session info & package versions (excerpt)

```
devtools::session_info()
#Session info
# version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# system   x86_64, mingw32
#Packages
# data.table      * 1.10.4  2017-02-01 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
# dplyr             0.5.0   2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)
# forcats           0.2.0   2017-01-23 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
# ggplot2         * 2.2.1   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
# magrittr        * 1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
# microbenchmark    1.4-2.1 2015-11-25 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
# scales            0.4.1   2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
# splitstackshape   1.4.2   2014-10-23 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
# tidyr             0.6.1   2017-01-10 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>My curiosity was piqued by [this exuberant comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409756/r-efficiently-separate-groups-in-data-frame#comment73879642_43409986) *Brilliant! Orders of magnitude faster!* to a `tidyverse` answer of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43409756/3817004) which was closed as a duplicate of this question.</sub>

Comment: Nice! Looks like room for improvement in cSplit and separate_rows (which are specifically designed to do this). Btw, cSplit also takes a fixed= arg and is a data.table-based package, so might as well give it DT instead of DF. Also fwiw, I don't think conversion from factor to char belongs in the benchmark (since it should be char to begin with). I checked and none of these changes does anything to the results qualitatively.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your suggestions to improve the benchmarks and for checking the effect on results. Will pick this up when doing an update after release of the next versions of `data.table`, `dplyr`, etc.

Comment: I think the approaches are not comparable, at least not in all occasions, because the datatable approaches only produce tables with the "selected" columns, while dplyr produces a result with all the columns (including the ones not involved in the analysis and without having to write their names in the function).

Comment: @Ferroao That's wrong, the data.tables approaches modify the "table" in place, all columns are kept, of course if you don't modify in place you get a filtered copy of only what you have asked for. In brief data.table approach is to not produce a resulting dataset but to update the dataset, that's the real difference between data.table and dplyr.

Comment: Really nice comparison! Maybe you can add in *matt_mod* and *jaap_dplyr*, when doing `strsplit` `fixed=TRUE`. As the other have it and this will have impact on timings. Since *R 4.0.0*, the default, when creating a `data.frame`, is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, so `as.character` could be removed.

Answer (score 151):

Several alternatives:

**1) two ways with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):**

```
library(data.table)
# method 1 (preferred)
setDT(v)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))), by = AB
         ][!is.na(director)]
# method 2
setDT(v)[, strsplit(as.character(director), ",", fixed=TRUE), by = .(AB, director)
         ][,.(director = V1, AB)]
```

**2) a [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) / [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) combination:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
v %>% 
  mutate(director = strsplit(as.character(director), ",")) %>%
  unnest(director)
```

**3) with [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) only:** With [`tidyr 0.5.0`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/13/tidyr-0-5-0/) (and later), you can also just use `separate_rows`:

```
separate_rows(v, director, sep = ",")
```

You can use the `convert = TRUE` parameter to automatically convert numbers into numeric columns.

With [`tidyr_1.3.0`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#tidyr-130) (and later), you can use `separate_longer_delim` (and `separate_rows` is now superseded):

```
separate_longer_delim(v, director, delim = ",")
```

**4) with base R:**

```
# if 'director' is a character-column:
stack(setNames(strsplit(df$director,','), df$AB))

# if 'director' is a factor-column:
stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$director),','), df$AB))
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this for multiple columns at once? For instance 3 columns that each have strings separated by ";" with each column having the same number of strings.  i.e. `data.table(id= "X21", a = "chr1;chr1;chr1", b="123;133;134",c="234;254;268")` becoming `data.table(id = c("X21","X21",X21"), 
 a=c("chr1","chr1","chr1"), b=c("123","133","134"), c=c("234","254","268"))` ?

Comment: wow just realized it already works for multiple columns at once - this is amazing!

Comment: @Reilstein could you share how you adapted this for multiple columns? I have the same use case, but unsure how to go about it.

Comment: @Moon_Watcher Method 1 in the answer above already works for multiple columns, which is what I thought was amazing.  `setDT(dt)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ";",fixed=TRUE))), by = ID]` is what worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to use the := assignment operator here in DT solutions, and would that have any additional benefits over assignment with the usual <- or = operators?

Comment: @MarkE. The `:=` assignment operator update a dataset by reference. This implicitly means that the number of row will stay the same. For these solutions, the number of rows is expanded because single rows are now broken into multiple rows. Hence, there is no place for using the `:=` operator.

Comment: @Jaap Ok, thanks.  I watched a presentation say that with Data.Table you don't see the normal assignment operator.  It must have meant "much of the time."

Comment: @MarkE. You can use the `:=` assignment operator when adding/updating/deleting columns. [See here for a more thorough explanation](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Comment: FYI `separate_rows` is deprecated in favor of `separate_longer_delim` now

Answer (score 53):

Naming your original data.frame `v`, we have this:

```
> s <- strsplit(as.character(v$director), ',')
> data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(v$AB, sapply(s, FUN=length)))
                      director AB
1                 Aaron Blaise  A
2                   Bob Walker  A
3               Akira Kurosawa  B
4               Alan J. Pakula  A
5                  Alan Parker  A
6           Alejandro Amenabar  B
7  Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu  B
8  Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu  B
9             Benicio Del Toro  B
10 Alejandro González Iñárritu  A
11                 Alex Proyas  B
12              Alexander Hall  A
13              Alfonso Cuaron  B
14            Alfred Hitchcock  A
15              Anatole Litvak  A
16              Andrew Adamson  B
17                 Marilyn Fox  B
18              Andrew Dominik  B
19              Andrew Stanton  B
20              Andrew Stanton  B
21                 Lee Unkrich  B
22              Angelina Jolie  B
23              John Stevenson  B
24               Anne Fontaine  B
25              Anthony Harvey  A
```

Note the use of `rep` to build the new AB column.  Here, `sapply` returns the number of names in each of the original rows.

Comment: I'm wondering if ` AB=rep(v$AB, unlist(sapply(s, FUN=length )))` might be easier to grasp than the more obscure `vapply`? Is there anything that makes `vapply` more appropriate here?

Comment: Nowadays `sapply(s, length)` could be replaced with `lengths(s)`.

Answer (score 32):

Late to the party, but another generalized alternative is to use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package that has a `direction` argument. Set this to `"long"` to get the result you specify:

```
library(splitstackshape)
head(cSplit(mydf, "director", ",", direction = "long"))
#              director AB
# 1:       Aaron Blaise  A
# 2:         Bob Walker  A
# 3:     Akira Kurosawa  B
# 4:     Alan J. Pakula  A
# 5:        Alan Parker  A
# 6: Alejandro Amenabar  B
```

Answer (score 2):

```
devtools::install_github("yikeshu0611/onetree")

library(onetree)

dd=spread_byonecolumn(data=mydata,bycolumn="director",joint=",")

head(dd)
            director AB
1       Aaron Blaise  A
2         Bob Walker  A
3     Akira Kurosawa  B
4     Alan J. Pakula  A
5        Alan Parker  A
6 Alejandro Amenabar  B
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Benchmark resulting using `strsplit` from *base* could currently be recommended to *Split a comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows*, as it was the fastest over a wide range of sizes:

```
s <- strsplit(v$director, ",", fixed=TRUE)
s <- data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(v$AB, lengths(s)))
```

Note that using `fixed=TRUE` has significant impact on timings.

[image: Curves showing computation time over number of rows]

Compared Methods:

```
met <- alist(base = {s <- strsplit(v$director, ",") #Matthew Lundberg
   s <- data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(v$AB, sapply(s, FUN=length)))}
 , baseLength = {s <- strsplit(v$director, ",") #Rich Scriven
   s <- data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(v$AB, lengths(s)))}
 , baseLeFix = {s <- strsplit(v$director, ",", fixed=TRUE)
   s <- data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(v$AB, lengths(s)))}
 , cSplit = s <- cSplit(v, "director", ",", direction = "long") #A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1
 , dt = s <- setDT(v)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, "," #Jaap
   , fixed=TRUE))), by = AB][!is.na(director)]
#, dt2 = s <- setDT(v)[, strsplit(director, "," #Jaap #Only Unique
#  , fixed=TRUE), by = .(AB, director)][,.(director = V1, AB)]
 , dplyr = {s <- v %>%  #Jaap
    mutate(director = strsplit(director, ",", fixed=TRUE)) %>%
    unnest(director)}
 , tidyr = s <- separate_rows(v, director, sep = ",") #Jaap
 , stack = s <- stack(setNames(strsplit(v$director, ",", fixed=TRUE), v$AB)) #Jaap
#, dt3 = {s <- setDT(v)[, strsplit(director, ",", fixed=TRUE), #Uwe #Only Unique
#  by = .(AB, director)][, director := NULL][, setnames(.SD, "V1", "director")]}
 , dt4 = {s <- setDT(v)[, .(director = unlist(strsplit(director, "," #Uwe
   , fixed = TRUE))), by = .(AB)]}
 , dt5 = {s <- vT[, .(director = unlist(strsplit(director, "," #Uwe
   , fixed = TRUE))), by = .(AB)]}
   )
```

Libraries:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(splitstackshape) #cSplit
library(data.table) #dt, dt2, dt3, dt4
#setDTthreads(1) #Looks like it has here minor effect
library(dplyr) #dplyr
library(tidyr) #dplyr, tidyr
```

Data:

```
v0 <- data.frame(director = c("Aaron Blaise,Bob Walker", "Akira Kurosawa", 
                        "Alan J. Pakula", "Alan Parker", "Alejandro Amenabar", "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu", 
                        "Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu,Benicio Del Toro", "Alejandro González Iñárritu", 
                        "Alex Proyas", "Alexander Hall", "Alfonso Cuaron", "Alfred Hitchcock", 
                        "Anatole Litvak", "Andrew Adamson,Marilyn Fox", "Andrew Dominik", 
                        "Andrew Stanton", "Andrew Stanton,Lee Unkrich", "Angelina Jolie,John Stevenson", 
                        "Anne Fontaine", "Anthony Harvey"), AB = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'))
```

Computation and Timing results:

```
n <- 10^(0:5)
x <- lapply(n, function(n) {v <- v0[rep(seq_len(nrow(v0)), n),]
  vT <- setDT(v)
  ti <- min(100, max(3, 1e4/n))
  microbenchmark(list = met, times = ti, control=list(order="block"))})

y <- do.call(cbind, lapply(x, function(y) aggregate(time ~ expr, y, median)))
y <- cbind(y[1], y[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)])
y[-1] <- y[-1] / 1e6 #ms
names(y)[-1] <- paste("n:", n * nrow(v0))
y #Time in ms
#         expr     n: 20    n: 200    n: 2000   n: 20000   n: 2e+05   n: 2e+06
#1        base 0.2989945 0.6002820  4.8751170  46.270246  455.89578  4508.1646
#2  baseLength 0.2754675 0.5278900  3.8066300  37.131410  442.96475  3066.8275
#3   baseLeFix 0.2160340 0.2424550  0.6674545   4.745179   52.11997   555.8610
#4      cSplit 1.7350820 2.5329525 11.6978975  99.060448 1053.53698 11338.9942
#5          dt 0.7777790 0.8420540  1.6112620   8.724586  114.22840  1037.9405
#6       dplyr 6.2425970 7.9942780 35.1920280 334.924354 4589.99796 38187.5967
#7       tidyr 4.0323765 4.5933730 14.7568235 119.790239 1294.26959 11764.1592
#8       stack 0.2931135 0.4672095  2.2264155  22.426373  289.44488  2145.8174
#9         dt4 0.5822910 0.6414900  1.2214470   6.816942   70.20041   787.9639
#10        dt5 0.5015235 0.5621240  1.1329110   6.625901   82.80803   636.1899
```

Note, methods like

```
(v <- rbind(v0[1:2,], v0[1,]))
#                 director AB
#1 Aaron Blaise,Bob Walker  A
#2          Akira Kurosawa  B
#3 Aaron Blaise,Bob Walker  A

setDT(v)[, strsplit(director, "," #Jaap #Only Unique
  , fixed=TRUE), by = .(AB, director)][,.(director = V1, AB)]
#         director AB
#1:   Aaron Blaise  A
#2:     Bob Walker  A
#3: Akira Kurosawa  B
```

return a `strsplit` for `unique` *director* and might be comparable with

```
tmp <- unique(v)
s <- strsplit(tmp$director, ",", fixed=TRUE)
s <- data.frame(director=unlist(s), AB=rep(tmp$AB, lengths(s)))
```

but to my understanding, this was not asked.