# Normalize data frame with list column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that maps some ids to a **list** of versions:

```r
id versions
 1  1, 2, 4
 2        1
 3     3, 4
```

It can be created with the following code:

```r
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3), 
  versions=c("1 2 4", "1", "3 4"), 
  stringsAsFactors=F)
df$versions <- strsplit(df$versions, " ")
```

Notice that each element of the `versions` column is a list.

How to normalize this data frame? I need to get a data frame like this:

```r
id version
 1       1
 1       2
 1       4
 2       1
 3       3
 3       4
```

Comment: hmm, lots of ways of asking the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stack` would be perfect for this:

```
stack(setNames(df$versions, df$id))
#   values ind
# 1      1   1
# 2      2   1
# 3      4   1
# 4      1   2
# 5      3   3
# 6      4   3
```

Comment: Nice! I'd just add `colnames(x) <- c("version", "id"); x <- x[, c("id", "version")]` to format the data frame `x` according to the question (assuming `x` is the data frame returned by `stack()`).

Answer (score 1):

I adapted and simplified the solution from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows) for future reference:

```
data.frame(id = rep(df$id, sapply(df$versions, length)),
      version = unlist(df$versions))
```

The new `id` column is computed by repeating each id according to the number of versions it has (i.e., the length of the list `versions`). The new `version` column is computed using `unlist`, that just returns a vector by concatenating all elements in the list.