# R - I'd like to split / partition a cell of strings with ";" as delimiter and create rows out of them

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to do this but not sure how.  For example, if I have...

```
ID  Name  Type                 Other

1   Andy  Test1; Test2; Test3  Other1; Other2; Other3
```

I'd like for R to return...

```
ID  Name  Type   Other

1   Andy  Test1  Other1
1   Andy  Test2  Other2
1   Andy  Test3  Other3
```

Is there any way to partition the data to get that?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows, along with all the linked questions on that previous question.

Comment: @thelatemail, but that answer doesn't include `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(mydf, c("Type", "Other"), ";", "long")`! :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto - a tragic oversight no doubt!

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a shot in a little bit and report back

Comment: I should have mentioned but there may be cases where there is nothing to split.  It works great when splitting but at rows that don't need it the resultant data frame has duplicate rows.  It can end up with many.  Wasn't sure what dictates it but some showed up with 20+ dupe rows

Comment: @AndyD, why don't you post a few more sample rows of data (preferably using `dput`) and also post your desired output. You're more likely to get better recommendations if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1="Test1; Test2; Test3"
str2="Other1; Other2; Other3"
Name="Andy"
Type=unlist(strsplit(str1,";"))
Other=unlist(strsplit(str2,";"))
cbind(Name,Type,Other)

> cbind(Name,Type,Other)
     Name   Type     Other    
[1,] "Andy" "Test1"  "Other1" 
[2,] "Andy" " Test2" " Other2"
[3,] "Andy" " Test3" " Other3"
```

Comment: Hi qjgod. Wouldn't this ignore the table structure?  The example I gave would be just one row in a much larger table that have different names / id's and different lengths for types / other ( count for the text would always be the same for these two though)

Comment: @Andy D,just call this function every row,and use the `rbind` to combine together

Comment: wouldn't it take a bit of time if there are a lot of rows then?  I have close to 200,000

Comment: @Andy D,if you need speed,use `Rcpp` to accelerate the program