# Add new column to a data.table; created using assign in loop

Tags: r, data.table, assign

I have a data.frame `keywordsCategory` which contains a set of phrases that I would like to categorize depending of words I want to check with.

For example, one of my "check terms" is *test1*, with correspond to category *cat1*. As the first observation of my data.frame is *This is a test1*, I need to include in a new column **category** with the corresponding category.

Because one observation can be assigned to more than one category, I though that the best option was to create independent subsets of my data.frame using `grepl` for lately binding all in a new data.frame

```
library(data.table)

wordsToCheck <- c("test1", "test2", "This")
categoryToAssign <- c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3")

keywordsCategory <- data.frame(Keyword=c("This is a test1", "This is a test2"))

for (i in 1:length(wordsToCheck)) {
        myOriginal <- wordsToCheck[i]
        myCategory <- categoryToAssign[i]
        dfToCreate <- paste0("withCategory",i)
        assign(dfToCreate, 
               data.table(keywordsCategory[grepl(paste0(".*",myOriginal,".*"),
                                                 keywordsCategory$Keyword)==TRUE,]))
        # this wont work :(
        # dfToCreate[,category:=myCategory]
}

# Create a list with all newly created data.tables
l.df <- lapply(ls(pattern="withCategory[0-9]+"), function(x) get(x))

# Create an aggregated dataframe with all Keywords data.tables
newdf <- do.call("rbind", l.df)
```

The subset > rbind works, but I am not beign able to assign the corresponging category to my new created data.tables. If I uncomment the line, I get following error:

> Error in `:=`(category, myCategory) :    Check that
>   is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for
>   use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

However, if I add the column manually once the loop is done, f.i:

```
withCategory1[,category:=myCategory]
```

It works correctly and the table output is as expected:

```
> withCategory1
                V1 category
1: This is a test1     cat2

tableOutput <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = c("This is a test1", 
"This is a test2"), class = "factor"), category = "cat2"), .Names = c("V1", 
"category"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

Which is the best/safest method to add a new column to a data.table when it is created inside a loop using the assign function? The solution doesn't need to use data.tables, as I only use it because my real data have millions of observations and I thought data.table would be faster.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Added a reproducible, minimal example dataset to the code

Comment: Hi please add a desired output table.

Comment: Thanks. Added expected output to question.

Comment: This is not how you use data.table. Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Roland, thanks. I added a bit of context to the question.

Comment: Based on your code, I would expect `cat1` & `cat3` for `This is a test1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative for your for-loop, you use a comination of `paste0`, `mapply` and `grepl` to get what you want:

```
# create a 'data.table'
newDT <- as.data.table(keywordsCategory)

# assign the correct categories to each row
newDT[, category := paste0(categoryToAssign[mapply(grepl, wordsToCheck, Keyword)], collapse = ','), 1:nrow(newDT)]
```

which gives:

```
> newDT
           Keyword  category
1: This is a test1 cat1,cat3
2: This is a test2 cat2,cat3
```

---

If you want to expand the category column to one category on each row, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows) for several methods how to do that. With for example:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(newDT, 'category', ",", direction = 'long')
```

you get:

```
           Keyword category
1: This is a test1     cat1
2: This is a test1     cat3
3: This is a test2     cat2
4: This is a test2     cat3
```