# Creating a variable using multiple variable

Tags: r

I am trying to clean a data set and  create 3 variables under the names: Adventure, Action and Comedy. The raw data set has 3000 observation (imported filename: dat). I am showing only few observations

```
id    Runtime        Genres                                       
37      75       animation, adventure, family, fantasy, musical   
1       162      action, adventure, fantasy, sci_fi       
95      126      action, fantasy   
100     101      comedy, drama, fantasy   
82      136      action, adventure, sci-fi    
99      117      animation, adventure, comedy, family, sport   
91      95       animation, comedy, crime, family
```

After importing the dataset in R separated all Genres into 5 using following  R code:

```
dat1 <- dat %>% separate (Genres, c("Genres1","Genres2" ,"Genres3" ,"Genres4" ,"Genres5" ), sep=",", extra = "drop", fill = "right")


id    Runtime    Genres1    Genres2    Genres3  Genres4  Genres5                                       
37      75       animation  adventure  family   fantasy  musical   
1       162      action     adventure  fantasy  sci_fi       
95      126      action     fantasy   
100     101      comedy     drama      fantasy   
82      136      action     adventure  sci-fi    
99      117      animation  adventure  comedy   family   sport   
91      95       animation  comedy     crime    family
```

How do collapse all the genres into 1 category each for action, adventure,  and comedy?

I tried using the following code:

created a empty column for adventure using

```
dat1 ["adventure"] <- NA

dat1$adventure <- ifelse(dat1$Genres1=="adventure",1,(ifelse(dat1$Genres2=="adventure",1,0)))
```

After suggestion shortened the code to

```
  dat1$adventure <- ifelse((dat1$Genres1=="adventure" | dat1$Genres2=="adventure" | dat1$Genres3=="adventure" | dat1$Genres4=="adventure" ),1, 0)


id    Runtime    Genres1    Genres2    Genres3  Genres4  Genres5  Adventure                                     
37      75       animation  adventure  family   fantasy  musical  0
1       162      action     adventure  fantasy  sci_fi            0
95      126      action     fantasy                               0
100     101      comedy     drama      fantasy                    0
82      136      action     adventure  sci-fi                     0
99      117      animation  adventure  comedy   family   sport    0   
91      95       animation  comedy     crime    family            0
```

The code was able to extract adventure for `Genres1` but returned zero for `Genres2`.

I have reedited the question. I tried things suggested but not sure how to go about it as there are 3000 observation.

After running suggestion

## list of genres, formation of vectors and assigning it to dat2

```
dat2 <- c( "adventure", "comedy", "action", "drama", "animation", "fantasy", "mystery", "family", "sci-fi", "thriller", "romance", "horror", "musical","history", "war", "documentary", "biography")
```

table(factor( dat2 ))                                                                                        table(factor( dat2 ))

```
 action   adventure   animation   biography      comedy documentary          drama 
      1           1           1           1           1           1           1 
 family     fantasy     history      horror     musical     mystery     romance 
      1           1           1           1           1           1           1 
 sci-fi    thriller         war 
      1           1           1
```

## creating the function

```
 fun1 <- function("adventure", "comedy", "action", "drama", "animation",
"fantasy", "mystery", "family", "sci-fi", "thriller", "romance", "horror", 
"musical","history", "war", "documentary", "biography")) {
 vector_of_cur_genres <- seperate(i, sep = ", ")
 result <- table(factor(vector_of_cur_genres, dat2))
 return(result)
 }  

  # Results         

 fun1 <- function("adventure", "comedy", "action", "drama", 
 "animation", "fantasy", "mystery", "family", "sci-fi", "thriller",  
 "romance", "horror", "musical","history", "war", "documentary", 
 "biography")) {
  Error: unexpected string constant in "fun1 <- function("adventure""
  >   vector_of_cur_genres <- separate(i, sep = ", ")
  Error: Please supply column name
  >   result <- table(factor(vector_of_cur_genres, dat2))
  Error in factor(vector_of_cur_genres, dat2) : 
  object 'vector_of_cur_genres' not found
  >   return(result)
  Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
   > }
   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

  mat <- mapply(fun1,dat2$Genres)
       Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'fun1' not found
```

Comment: FYI, there’s no need to create an empty new column before assigning to it: the assignment creates it anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Possibly, convert your data from wide to long, then table summary.

Comment: See also: [Split comma-separated column into separate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows)

Comment: As a simplification, this can be shortened into a single `ifelse` function:   `ifelse((dat1$Genres1=="adventure" | dat1$Genres2=="adventure"),1, 0)`

Comment: The code returns output for Genres1 as 1 but for other Genres(2-5) returns NA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of table and factor to get what you want.  First you want to make sure that all of the Genres as spelled exactly the same each time (`"Adventure" != "adventure"`).  Then you should create a vector with all of the possible genres `c("Adventure", "Comedy", "Drama", ...")`.

For each row you then call `table(factor(genres, list_of_possible_genres))` and it will return a table of counts.  You can then construct a matrix with something like this

```
mat <- mapply(
    function(i) {
        table(factor(separate(i, ...),list_of_possible_genres))
    },df$Genres)
#you want to use the original Data.Frame after import

new.df <- cbind(df,mat) #they should both have the same number of rows here
```

make the `...` in the separate call the same as in your original function.  If you have any questions as to what of the individual functions or steps does, I can explain in the comments.

I define a function right in the mapply call `function (i) ...` this is similar to defining a `lambda` in Python.  That function takes in a string of genres and returns a named vector of counts of how many times each possible genre appeared.

EDIT:

```
fun1 <- function(string_of_genres)) {
    vector_of_cur_genres <- seperate(i, sep = ", ")
    result <- table(factor(vector_of_cur_genres, list_of_possible_genres))
    return(result)
}
mat <- mapply(fun1,df$Genres)
```

Comment: @ Adam: I am a beginner to R. do you want to work on the raw imported data frame for this steps? Could you please explain the matrix function and cbind?

Comment: `cbind` is the easy one.  What it does is to take a bunch of matrices or data.frames and attaches the columns to each other.  So what will happen in the call `cbind(df,mat)` is that the data.frame will have the columns of the matrix tagged on to the end.

`mapply` is a vectorization function which means it takes a vector, matrix or list and then applies the given function to it and then gives back the results from each of the function calls.  `mapply` is part of the `*apply` family of functions on which there is a lot of literature about explaining their nuances and differences.

Comment: check my edits.  You do want to call this on the data.frame from the first step.  before you split the data.  If you take a look, you will be splitting the data in the code elsewhere

Comment: Thats like a `lambda` call.  One of the parameters to mapply is supposed to be a function, but instead of writing, naming, and passing that function, I skip the naming step and write the function inside of the mapply call.  `function (i)` and everything until the comma after `list_of_genres` is the new function that was defined to be used by mapply.  That function will be called on each element in the list that was passed to it as a second argument.

Comment: see my edit separating out the function naming.  Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. This is so complicated and above my knowledge. I was able to create vectors but where do you insert raw data in whole process when you create fun1?

Comment: In `mat <- mapply(fun1, dat$Genres)`  The second argument should be the **unseparated** Genres.  The ones that you have in the dat structure right after import.  fun1 is just a function that you call ~3000 times when you apply it to each element of dat$Genres

Comment: after defining fun1, try running `mat <- mapply(fun1, dat$Genres)` and see what it spits out.  Put the call and results into your questions if it doesn't work and we can go from there

Comment: It did not work, will let everyone know if things work