# Split multiple columns into rows

Tags: r, split, strsplit, splitstackshape

I'm working with a very raw set of data and need to shape it up in order to work with it. I am trying to split selected columns based on seperator `'|'`

```
d <- data.frame(id = c(022,565,893,415),
     name = c('c|e','m|q','w','w|s|e'), 
     score = c('e','k|e','e|k|e', 'e|o'))
```

Is it possible to split the dataframe at one so it looks like this in the end.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(22,22,565,565,565,565,893,893,893,415,415,415,415,415,415),
            name = c('c','e','m','m','q','q','w','w','w','w','w','s','s','e','e'),
            score = c('e','e','k','e','k','e','e','k','e','e','o','e','o','e','o'))
```

So far I've tried various different string split funtions but haven't had much luck :(

Can anybody help?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770

Comment: Just use a double `cSplit`: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(cSplit(d, 'name', sep = '|', 'long'), 'score', sep = '|', 'long')`

Comment: [V2 of "splitstackshape"](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/tree/v2.0) will introduce a function called `cartesian_split()` which can be used as `cartesian_split(d, c("name", "score"), "[|]", fixed = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple base R approach in two steps:

1) split the columns:

```
x <- lapply(d[-1], strsplit, "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

2) expand and combine:

```
d2 <- setNames(do.call(rbind, Map(expand.grid, d$id, x$name, x$score)), names(d))
```

The result is then:

```
#    id name score
#1   22    c     e
#2   22    e     e
#3  565    m     k
#4  565    q     k
#5  565    m     e
#6  565    q     e
#7  893    w     e
#8  893    w     k
#9  893    w     e
#10 415    w     e
#11 415    s     e
#12 415    e     e
#13 415    w     o
#14 415    s     o
#15 415    e     o
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also 2 line `tidyr` \ `dplyr` solution.

The `tidyr` package has a function called `separate_rows` that will do what you need. You need two separate the rows in two operations with the nested elements not being equal.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- separate_rows(d, name, sep = "\\|") %>%
separate_rows(score, sep = "\\|")
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that on mobile!

Comment: what if I have more than 1000 columns?

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `unnest` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% mutate(name=strsplit(name,split="[|]")) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      unnest() %>% 
      mutate(score=strsplit(score,split="[|]")) %>% 
      unnest()
##Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
##Groups: id [4]
##
##      id  name score
##   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
##1     22     c     e
##2     22     e     e
##3    565     m     k
##4    565     m     e
##5    565     q     k
##6    565     q     e
##7    893     w     e
##8    893     w     k
##9    893     w     e
##10   415     w     e
##11   415     w     o
##12   415     s     e
##13   415     s     o
##14   415     e     e
##15   415     e     o
```