# Divide lines of a dataframe in multiple lines

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Suppose you have a dataframe with an Id x and a string y :

```
x  y
1  a-b-c
2  d-e
```

I want the following dataframe :

```
x  y
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  d
2  e
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)


dff <- structure(list(x = 1:2, 
               y = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a-b-c","d-e"), 
              class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y"), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-2L))

dff %>%
    separate_rows(y)

#  x y
#1 1 a
#2 1 b
#3 1 c
#4 2 d
#5 2 e
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dff, "y", "-", "long")
#   x y
#1: 1 a
#2: 1 b
#3: 1 c
#4: 2 d
#5: 2 e
```