# Look up of comma separated data in another table

Tags: r

I do have 2 tables where in the table data frame consist data with comma separated values.

Need to find out which category present in lookup data frame i.e. in Option 1 out of "Cat A, Cat B, Cat C" which category is present. if found, need to show the score against it.

incase multiple instance found, we need to show the score of first occurrence hence in first case Cat C and Cat Z both comes under Option 1 however we need to show the score for Cat C only which is 2.

**Table**

```
Option           | Cat 
-----             ------   
Option 1         | Cat A, Cat B, Cat C, Cat Z
Option 2         | Cat X, Cat Y, Cat Z, Cat B
Option 3         | Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T 
Option 1         | Cat T 
Option 3         | Cat E, Cat F
```

**Lookup**

```
Cat   |   Option    |   Score

Cat A |   Option 2   |   8
Cat B |   Option 3   |   3
Cat C |   Option 1   |   2
Cat X |   Option 3   |   9
Cat Y |   Option 1   |   1
Cat Z |   Option 2   |   1
Cat P |   Option 3   |   2
Cat Q |   Option 2   |   9
Cat R |   Option 1   |   4
Cat S |   Option 4   |   0
Cat T |   Option 1   |   5
Cat E |   Option 4   |   1
Cat F |   Option 3   |   10
```

**Output**

```
 Option      |     Cat                                |     Found_cat    |     Score
 Option 1    |     Cat A, Cat B, Cat C                |     Cat C        |     2
 Option 2    |     Cat X, Cat Y, Cat Z, Cat B          |     Cat Z        |     1
 Option 3    |     Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T  |     Cat P        |     2
 Option 1    |     Cat T                              |     Cat T        |     5
 Option 3    |     Cat E, Cat F                       |     Cat F        |     10
```

**R Code for creating dataframe**

```
Table <- data.frame(Option = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 3"),
                 Cat = c("Cat A, Cat B, Cat C", "Cat X, Cat Y,Cat Z, Cat B", "Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T", "Cat T", "Cat E, Cat F"))

lookup <-data.frame(Cat = c("Cat A", "Cat B", "Cat C", "Cat X", "Cat Y", "Cat Z", "Cat P", "Cat Q", "Cat R", "Cat S", "Cat T", "Cat E", "Cat F"),
                    Options = c("Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 2", "Option 1", "Option 4", "Option 1", "Option 4", "Option 3"),
                    Score = c(8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2, 9, 4, 0, 5, 1, 10)) 



output <- data.frame(Option = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 3"),
                     Cat = c("Cat A, Cat B, Cat C", "Cat X, Cat Y, Cat Z, Cat B,", "Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T", "Cat T", "Cat E, Cat F"),
                     Found_cat = c("Cat C", "Cat Z", "Cat P", "Cat T", "Cat F"),
                     Score = c(2, 1, 2, 5, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks @GGamba for your edit, Would you be able to help me on this?

Comment: Hi Ayush, what have you tried so far?  Or have you just set up the data?  Hopefully you'll share with us what you've attempted so we have a jumping off point.

Comment: Hi Joy, Thanks for your comment, as of now i am not able to land on starting point. I just identified the approach. though i am also working on this using for loop however this might not be a idle approach because in my requirement there are more than 25k+ rows. :(

Comment: Since i was in big hurry and exhausted now by working more than 25 hours now hence your help would be really appreciable.

Comment: I think a first step for you is to un-aggregate the comma separated data into separate rows.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows/31514711#31514711 for several approaches.  Then you can do a merge to combine your cleaned up data.

Answer (score 2):

I just give a quick try using loop:

```
Table <- data.frame(Option = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 3"),
                Cat = c("Cat A, Cat B, Cat C", "Cat X, Cat Y, Cat Z, Cat B", "Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T", "Cat T", "Cat E, Cat F"), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

lookup <-data.frame(Cat = c("Cat A", "Cat B", "Cat C", "Cat X", "Cat Y", "Cat Z", "Cat P", "Cat Q", "Cat R", "Cat S", "Cat T", "Cat E", "Cat F"),
                Options = c("Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 3", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 2", "Option 1", "Option 4", "Option 1", "Option 4", "Option 3"),
                Score = c(8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2, 9, 4, 0, 5, 1, 10), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)
app = matrix(nrow = nrow(Table), ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:nrow(Table)) {
lookup.cats = lookup$Cat[lookup$Options == Table$Option[i]]
Table.cats = unlist(strsplit(Table$Cat[i], split = ', '))
found.cat = intersect(lookup.cats, Table.cats)
score = lookup$Score[which(lookup$Cat == found.cat & 
                               lookup$Options == Table$Option[i])]
app[i, 1] = found.cat
app[i, 2] = score
}
app = as.data.frame(app)
names(app) = c('Found_cat', 'Score')
cbind(Table, app)
```

Comment: Awesome Sean, You are really a savior. A BIG THANK YOU!

Comment: @ayushvarshney note that there is a missing space before 'Cat Z' in your data frame Table, I couldn't edit your question now, but I fixed it in answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, i corrected it in my question as well, just a suggestion to check sotos code as well which seems to be really fast for larger data sets....

Comment: @ayushvarshney yes, I was trying a short version after trying loop, and his code pops up, really awesome one.

Comment: No problem, You spend time for my problem which is really nice. Cannot share my gratitudes with words. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option,

```
library(tidyverse)

Table %>% 
  unnest(Cat = strsplit(as.character(Cat), ', ')) %>% 
  inner_join(lookup, by = c('Option', 'Cat')) %>%
  select(Cat, Score) %>% 
  rename(Cat_Found = Cat) %>% 
  bind_cols(Table, .)

#    Option                               Cat Cat_Found Score
#1 Option 1               Cat A, Cat B, Cat C     Cat C     2
#2 Option 2        Cat X, Cat Y, Cat Z, Cat B     Cat Z     1
#3 Option 3 Cat P, Cat Q, Cat R, Cat S, Cat T     Cat P     2
#4 Option 1                             Cat T     Cat T     5
#5 Option 3                      Cat E, Cat F     Cat F    10
```

Comment: Really nice approach Sotos, thanks a lot for pointing out the inconsistencies however i really like the way you handled the inconsistencies with your code. i have amended the changes in my question as well for the suggested second point however i am unable to get your first point.

Comment: Thanks. Minor note here: If you get any warnings while running it it's due to some of your variables being factors. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: anyways, thanks a lot for your time and help here, much appreciated.

Comment: My first comment was that in your reproducible data, the delimeter between CatY and CatZ in the second row string of Table, was missing a comma...just a tiny typo

Comment: could you please help me once again, so lets say table consist Option 1         | Cat A, Cat B, Cat C, Cat T in this case i wanted to show the score for first occurrence i.e. Cat C score, how can i handle this situation.