# Applying a transform that creates new rows to a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like:

```
     beginTime    endTime duration          data    splits
 1: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 1     24,38
 2: 1497902556 1497902618       92  data chunk 2  24,60, 8
 3: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 3     24,38
 4: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 4     24,38
 5: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 5     24,38
 6: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 6     24,38
 7: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 7     24,38
 8: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 8     24,38
 9: 1497902556 1497902618       62  data chunk 9     24,38
10: 1497902556 1497902618       62 data chunk 10     24,38
```

that I'd like to convert to one that looks like:

```
     beginTime    endTime duration          data splits
 1: 1497902556 1497902580       62  data chunk 1  24
 2: 1497902580 1497902618       62  data chunk 1  38
 3: 1497902556 1497902580       62  data chunk 2  24
 4: 1497902580 1497902640       62  data chunk 2  60
 5: 1497902640 1497902648       62  data chunk 2   8
 6: 1497902556 1497902580       62  data chunk 3  24
 7: 1497902580 1497902618       62  data chunk 3  38
 8: 1497902556 1497902580       62  data chunk 4  24
 9: 1497902580 1497902618       62  data chunk 4  38
10: 1497902556 1497902580       62  data chunk 5  24
11: 1497902580 1497902618       62  data chunk 5  38
...
```

That is, I want to distribute the parts of the splits across the rows and adjust the start and end times as appropriate.

For a given input row, what I need to do is (in pseudo-code):

```
function(row) {
  beginTime = row$beginTime
  for (split in row$splits) {
    endTime = beginTime + split
    emitRow(beginTime, endTime, row$duration, row$data, split)
    beginTime = endTime
  }
}
```

(`emitRow` is a function that simply creates a new row - for each of the rows in my sample data, this function would call emitRow twice each)

I thought I'd start with `melt`, but I can't seem to convince it to split the `splits` column and now I'm a little stuck. I can get the total number of rows needed after splitting via `sum(unlist(Map(length,t$splits)))`.

Any recommendations on a next step?

**UPDATE 1: possible duplicate of [Split comma-separated column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows)**

I can use `unnest` to get my data into the multiple rows, but it doesn't update the `beginTime` and `endTime` like I would want.

```
> t
     beginTime    endTime durationInSeconds   splits                                                                      measures
 1: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                         1.000000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.000169
 2: 1497902556 1497902648                92 24,60, 8 1.000000e+00,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,3.171942e+13
 3: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                                          1,   697,   697,   697,   697,485809
 4: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0
 5: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38 1.000000e+00,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,8.401193e+23
 6: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                                     1.0000,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.0961
 7: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0
 8: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0
 9: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38                   1.0000000,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.6669444
10: 1497902556 1497902618                62    24,38 1.000000e+00,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,8.751736e-06
> t2 = data.table(t %>% unnest(splits, .drop=FALSE))
> t2
     beginTime    endTime durationInSeconds                                                                      measures splits
 1: 1497902556 1497902618                62                         1.000000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.000169     24
 2: 1497902556 1497902618                62                         1.000000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.013000,0.000169     38
 3: 1497902556 1497902648                92 1.000000e+00,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,3.171942e+13     24
 4: 1497902556 1497902648                92 1.000000e+00,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,3.171942e+13     60
 5: 1497902556 1497902648                92 1.000000e+00,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,5.632000e+06,3.171942e+13      8
 6: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                          1,   697,   697,   697,   697,485809     24
 7: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                          1,   697,   697,   697,   697,485809     38
 8: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     24
 9: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     38
10: 1497902556 1497902618                62 1.000000e+00,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,8.401193e+23     24
11: 1497902556 1497902618                62 1.000000e+00,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,9.165802e+11,8.401193e+23     38
12: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                     1.0000,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.0961     24
13: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                     1.0000,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.3100,0.0961     38
14: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     24
15: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     38
16: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     24
17: 1497902556 1497902618                62                                                                   1,0,0,0,0,0     38
18: 1497902556 1497902618                62                   1.0000000,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.6669444     24
19: 1497902556 1497902618                62                   1.0000000,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.8166667,0.6669444     38
20: 1497902556 1497902618                62 1.000000e+00,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,8.751736e-06     24
21: 1497902556 1497902618                62 1.000000e+00,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,2.958333e-03,8.751736e-06     38
```

**UPDATE 2: Reproducable data sample**

I don't have data for the "after", just the before:

```
> dput(t)
structure(list(beginTime = c(1497902556L, 1497902556L, 1497902556L, 
1497902556L, 1497902556L, 1497902556L, 1497902556L, 1497902556L, 
1497902556L, 1497902556L), endTime = c(1497902618L, 1497902648L, 
1497902618L, 1497902618L, 1497902618L, 1497902618L, 1497902618L, 
1497902618L, 1497902618L, 1497902618L), durationInSeconds = c(62L, 
92L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L), splits = list(c(24, 
38), c(24, 60, 8), c(24, 38), c(24, 38), c(24, 38), c(24, 38), 
    c(24, 38), c(24, 38), c(24, 38), c(24, 38)), measures = list(
    c(1, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.000169), c(1, 5632000, 
    5632000, 5632000, 5632000, 3.1719424e+13), c(1, 697, 697, 
    697, 697, 485809), c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 916580200000, 
    916580200000, 916580200000, 916580200000, 8.401193e+23), 
    c(1, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.0961), c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 0.81666666, 0.81666666, 0.81666666, 
    0.81666666, 0.66694444), c(1, 0.0029583334, 0.0029583334, 
    0.0029583334, 0.0029583334, 8.7517365e-06))), .Names = c("beginTime", 
"endTime", "durationInSeconds", "splits", "measures"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x105008578>)
```

Comment: @HubertL I believe it's not really a dupe because splitting up one column is only the first part of the problem.

Comment: @UweBlock that is hard to judge as there is no [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I think I'm going to try a different approach - have something *other than R* do the transform I want and then process the result in R.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be:

```
library(data.table)

dt2 <- dt[rep(1:nrow(dt), times = sapply(strsplit(dt$splits,","),length))][,splits2 := as.integer(unlist(strsplit(dt$splits,",")))]
dt3 <- dt2[,c("beginTime","endTime") := list(beginTime + shift(splits2,fill=0L), beginTime + splits2 + shift(splits2,fill=0L)), by = .(data)]

head(dt3)
#    beginTime    endTime duration         data splits splits2
#1: 1497902556 1497902580       62 data chunk 1  24,38      24
#2: 1497902580 1497902618       62 data chunk 1  24,38      38
#3: 1497902556 1497902580       62 data chunk 2  24,38      24
#4: 1497902580 1497902618       62 data chunk 2  24,38      38
#5: 1497902556 1497902580       62 data chunk 3  24,38      24
#6: 1497902580 1497902618       62 data chunk 3  24,38      38
```