# How to break comma-separated values in different rows in r

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe in r

```
  names       values
   abc          34
   def          12,23
   rty          34,67,89
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
   names       values
   abc          34
   def_1        12
   def_2        23
   rty_1        34
   rty_2        67
   rty_3        89
```

I am able to separate the values in different rows but how can I alter the `names` column as desired

```
   splitdat <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(df$values[3], ","))
   splitdat <- data.frame(apply(splitdat, 2, as.numeric))
   colnames(splitdat)[1] <- "column1"
```

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, values, sep=",") %>%
      mutate(names = make.unique(names, sep="_"))
```

---

Or we create a sequence column by group and then `paste`

```
separate_rows(df1, values, sep=",") %>% 
       group_by(names) %>%
       mutate(names1 = if(n()>1) paste(names, row_number(), sep="_") else names) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       select(names1, values) %>% 
       rename(names= names1)
```

Comment: I want only comma seperated to be break up in different rows. above code also breaks cells which are seperated by white spaces. And how can I number `abc_1,abc_2` if it has two comma seperated entries

Comment: I got it by `seperate_rows(d1,sep = ",")`

Comment: How can I achieve rows which are seperated in different rows to be named as `abc_1 ,abc_2`  ?

Comment: How can we achieve the desired column `names` ?

Comment: @Neil Updated the post with `make.unique`.   Please let me know if that works.  Or else