# convert data.frame to another data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data.frames as follows:

```
dt2017 = data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:5],year=2017,city1=c(0,1,0,1,0),city2=c(0,0,1,0,0),city3=c(1,0,1,0,1),city4=c(0,0,0,0,1))
dt2017
id year city1 city2 city3 city4
1:  A 2017     0     0     1     0
2:  B 2017     1     0     0     0
3:  C 2017     0     1     1     0
4:  D 2017     1     0     0     0
5:  E 2017     0     0     1     1

dt2016 = data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:5],year=2016,city1=c(0,0,0,0,1),city2=c(0,0,0,1,0),city3=c(0,0,1,0,1),city4=c(1,1,0,0,1))
dt2016
   id year city1 city2 city3 city4|
1:  A 2016     0     0     0     1
2:  B 2016     0     0     0     1
3:  C 2016     0     0     1     0
4:  D 2016     0     1     0     0
5:  E 2016     1     0     1     1
```

"1" in the data.frame can represent working in the city. For example, in 2016, A,B and E work in the same city4. First, I want to get following data.frame:

```
   id  2016   2017   2016+2017
1: A    B;E    C;E      B;C;E
2: B    A;E      D      A;D;E
3: C      E    A;E        A;E
4: D     NA      B          B
5: E  A;B;C    A;C      A;B;C
```

Second, I want to get a data.frame like this:

```
id     relation
 A         B
 A         C
 A         E
 B         A
 B         D
 B         E
 D         B
 E         A
 E         B
 E         C
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split comma-separated column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve what you want, but it is not very pretty. Still it does what you want.

```
library(plyr)

dt2017$id <- as.character(dt2017$id)
dt2016$id <- as.character(dt2016$id)
id <- dt2017$id

my_function <- function(dt, x){
    tmp <- data.frame(id=id, dt[,dt[dt$id==x,]==1])
    tmp$ind <- sapply(1:nrow(tmp), function(x) return(sum(tmp[x, 2:ncol(tmp)])))
    return(paste(tmp[tmp$ind > 0 & tmp$id !=x,"id"], collapse=";"))
}

results1 <- data.frame(Year2016 = sapply(id, function(x) return(my_function(dt2016,x))),
    Year2017 = sapply(id, function(x) return(my_function(dt2017,x))))


my_function2 <- function(dt, x){
    tmp <- data.frame(id=id, dt[,dt[dt$id==x,]==1])
    tmp$ind <- sapply(1:nrow(tmp), function(x) return(sum(tmp[x, 2:ncol(tmp)])))
    if(length(tmp[tmp$ind > 0 & tmp$id !=x,"id"])!=0){
        return(data.frame(id=x, relation=tmp[tmp$ind > 0 & tmp$id !=x,"id"]))
    }
}


results_tmp <- rbind(adply(.data=id, .margins=1, .fun= function(x) return(my_function2(dt2016,x))), 
    adply(.data=id, .margins=1, .fun= function(x) return(my_function2(dt2017,x))))[, c("id", "relation")]

results2 <- unique(results_tmp[order(as.character(results_tmp$id)),])



fun_tmp <- function(x) return(paste(x, collapse=";"))
bothyear_tmp <- aggregate(list(relation=results2$relation), by=list(id=results2 $"id"), FUN=fun_tmp)
results1$BothYear <- bothyear_tmp[order(as.character(bothyear_tmp$id)),"relation"]
```

And here are the results:

```
results1
 Year2016 Year2017 BothYear
A      B;E      C;E    B;E;C
B      A;E        D    A;E;D
C        E      A;E      E;A
D                 B        B
E    A;B;C      A;C    A;B;C

results2
 id relation
 A        B
 A        E
 A        C
 B        A
 B        E
 B        D
 C        E
 C        A
 D        B
 E        A
 E        B
 E        C
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks very much. I guess there may be some functions in r package sna or igraph that can do this, but I can not find exact function. I hope someone can do it in a prettier way.