# contingency table with strings

Tags: r, contingency

I have this data frame `glimpse(df)`

```
Observations: 2,211
Variables: 3
$ city       <chr> "Las Vegas", "Pittsburgh", "Las Vegas", "Phoenix", "Las Vegas", "Las Veg...
$ categories <chr> "c(\"Korean\", \"Sushi Bars\")", "c(\"Japanese\", \"Sushi Bars\")", "Tha...
$ is_open    <chr> "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1...
```

Here is a small `dput()`

```
structure(list(city = c("Las Vegas", "Pittsburgh", "Las Vegas", 
"Phoenix", "Las Vegas"), categories = c("c(\"Korean\", \"Sushi Bars\")", 
"c(\"Japanese\", \"Sushi Bars\")", "Thai", "c(\"Sushi Bars\", \"Japanese\")", 
"Korean"), is_open = c("0", "0", "1", "0", "1")), .Names = c("city", 
"categories", "is_open"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data consists different cities `city` with different cuisines `categories`. 
I want to make a contingency table to visualize which cuisines are associated with closings `(is_opem = 0)` or openings `(is_open = 1)`.

I want to do this with a contingency table. To do so I tried this one but I got this error:

```
xtabs(is_open ~., data = df)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

When I convert the variables `as.factor()` I get lots of tables, not one. Is there a way to this so ít´s looking like below?

```
Categorie/City          Las Vegas     Pittsburgh
           Korean       50/50         30/70
           Sushi Bars   40/60         40/60
```

The numbers in the columns are the frequencies of the closings `(is_opem = 0)` and openings `(is_open = 1)` for each category per city (e.g. for Korean in Las Vegas the distribution for closings(0) and openings(1) is 50/50).

Comment: please post the output of `dput(df)` instead of `glimpse(df)`

Comment: Could you explain your output again, I do not understand how these numbers are generated. To my understanding you either divide each row/col by total counts, rowsum or colsum in contingeny tables (or leave the counts). In addition, I think your data structure should not inlcude two categories in one cell, instead one row should be generated per category, this would at least resemble a correct "long format" or the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `data.table` to `cast` your data using a counting function based on `stri_count` from `stringi` package. The latter might also be achieved via `table` or `sum(grepl())` with `ifelse` constructs (depending on the required flexibility with respect to the data structure, speed requirements, etc.). Please note that I have also reformatted your data into more clean "long format" with the aid of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows). This reformatting might be skipped if you format your data this way right from the start. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
#your data
df <- structure(list(city = c("Las Vegas", "Pittsburgh", "Las Vegas", "Phoenix", "Las Vegas")
                       ,categories = c("c(\"Korean\", \"Sushi Bars\")", 
                                     "c(\"Japanese\", \"Sushi Bars\")", "Thai", "c(\"Sushi Bars\", \"Japanese\")", 
                                     "Korean")
                       ,is_open = c("0", "0", "1", "0", "1"))
                       ,.Names = c("city",  "categories", "is_open"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
library(stringi)                                  

#format data to correct "long format"
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, categories := gsub("c\\(\"|\"|\"\\)", "", categories)]
DT <- DT[, .(categories = unlist(strsplit(as.character(categories), ", ", fixed = TRUE))), 
         by = .(city, is_open)]
#           city is_open categories
# 1:  Las Vegas       0     Korean
# 2:  Las Vegas       0 Sushi Bars
# 3: Pittsburgh       0   Japanese
# 4: Pittsburgh       0 Sushi Bars
# 5:  Las Vegas       1       Thai
# 6:  Las Vegas       1     Korean
# 7:    Phoenix       0 Sushi Bars
# 8:    Phoenix       0   Japanese

#specify all_unique_count_items to also cover items that are not present in x
calc_count_distr <-  function(x, all_unique_count_items) {

    count_distribution <- sapply(all_unique_count_items, function(y) {
                                     100*round(sum(stri_count_fixed(x, y))/length(x), d =2)
                                })
    paste(count_distribution, collapse = "/")
}

dcast.data.table(DT, categories ~ city, value.var = "is_open"
                 ,fun.aggregate = function(x) calc_count_distr(x, all_unique_count_items = unique(DT$is_open))
                 ,fill = NA)
#   categories Las Vegas Phoenix Pittsburgh
#1:   Japanese        NA   100/0      100/0
#2:     Korean     50/50      NA         NA
#3: Sushi Bars     100/0   100/0      100/0
#4:       Thai     0/100      NA         NA
```

Comment: you probably want to perform all of the cleaning _after_ converting to `data.table`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, changed it. (I know I could have piped the `data.table` commands during cleaning/reformatting, however, I wanted to maintain easy readability)