# reshaping when there is no variable value in r

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I have a data.frame that has two columns only. one is `barcodeid` and the other is `gene`.

```
barcodeid gene
M001-M008-S137 IL12RB1
M001-M008-S137 IL7RA
M001-M008-S137 LMP1
M001-M012-S080 CRLF2
M001-M012-S080 ICOS
M001-M012-S080 IL7RA
```

I want to end up with this table:

```
barcodeID geneSequence
M001-M008-S137 IL12RB1-IL7RA-LMP1
M001-M012-S080 CRLF2-ICOS-IL7RA
```

I've looked up `reshape`, `dcast`, `spread`, `gather` in r and as far as I can tell these are not the functions that would allow me to do this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Thanks Frank, this worked as well. I'm doing it this way purely for aesthetic reasons because this is how people want to see the data presented in a table. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more options:

```
reshape2::dcast(DT, barcodeid ~ ., paste, collapse="-")

aggregate(. ~ barcodeid, DT, paste, collapse="-")
```

`aggregate` has the benefit of auto-naming as "gene" instead of "." here, though if a new name is needed, I guess they're interchangeable, followed by...

```
names(res)[2] <- "geneSequence"
```

To revert the change, one approach is:

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(res, "geneSequence", "-", direction = "long")
```

See [Split comma-separated column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773770/1191259) for many more options.

Comment: if I wanted to make my first table again how could I do that? How can I split the geneSequence into three rows with the same barcodeid but one gene in each row?

Comment: @HibaShaban I've edited in one way to approach it with a link to more. I'm not sure what the tidyr or base R ways would be

Answer (score 2):

Assume `df` is your data.frame and a combination of R base functions would be helpful:

```
> x <- lapply(split(df$gene, df$barcodeid), paste0, collapse="-")
> data.frame(barcodeid=names(x), geneSequence=unlist(x), row.names = NULL)
       barcodeid       geneSequence
1 M001-M008-S137 IL12RB1-IL7RA-LMP1
2 M001-M012-S080   CRLF2-ICOS-IL7RA
```

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr you could do:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(barcodeid) %>% 
  mutate(geneSequence = paste(gene, collapse = "-")) %>%
  select(-gene) %>% 
  slice(1)


# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   barcodeid [2]
   barcodeid       geneSequence
      <fctr>              <chr>
1 M001-M008-S137 IL12RB1-IL7RA-LMP1
2 M001-M012-S080   CRLF2-ICOS-IL7RA
```