# Convert multiple value fields to factor

Tags: r

Reading input from a csv file leaves me with an odd field containing multiple values e.g.

```
 Title                Genres
1     A [Item1, Item2, Item3]
2     B                      
3     C        [Item4, Item1]


df <- data.frame(c("A","B","C"), c("[Item1, Item2, Item3]","","[Item4, Item1]"), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df) <- c("Title","Genres")
```

A function to retrieve the individual tokens

```
extractGenre <- function(genreVector){
  strsplit(substring(genreVector,2,nchar(genreVector)-1),", ")
}
```

I am a bit lost on how to convert *Item 1,... Item 4* into factors and append them to the dataframe. While apply lets me execute the function on each row, how would the next step look like?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Perhaps, this Q is helpful [Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773770/3817004)?

Comment: @Uwe thank you for the link. Just what I was searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(Genres=gsub('\\[|\\]|\\s+','',Genres)) %>%  #remove []
       separate(Genres,paste0('Gen',1:3)) %>%             #separate Genres to multiple columns
       gather(key,Genres,-Title) %>% select(-key) %>%     #Gather to Genres columns
       filter(!is.na(Genres)) %>% arrange(Title,Genres) %>%    #filter and arrange
       mutate(Genres=as.factor(Genres))     


   Title Genres
1     A  Item1
2     A  Item2
3     A  Item3
4     B       
5     C  Item1
6     C  Item4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I approached it a bit differently. I used dplyr and grepl:

```
    df <- data.frame(c("A","B","C"), c("[Item1, Item2, Item3]","","[Item4, Item1]"), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(df) <- c("Title","Genres")
    df
    df1<-df%>%
      mutate(Item1 = ifelse(grepl("Item1",Genres), T,F),
             Item2 = ifelse(grepl("Item2",Genres), T,F),
             Item3 = ifelse(grepl("Item3",Genres), T,F),
             Item4 = ifelse(grepl("Item4",Genres), T,F))

 Title                Genres Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
1     A [Item1, Item2, Item3]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2     B                       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3     C        [Item4, Item1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can used the function `separate()` as Uwe proposed, but it seems that the order of your Genre is not always the same. One option is to create new column with `mutate()`, and use the function `grepl()` in order to identify if each tokens is present.

```
df %>% 
    mutate(
        Item1 = grepl('Item1', Genres),
        Item2 = grepl('Item2', Genres),
        Item3 = grepl('Item3', Genres),
        Item4 = grepl('Item4', Genres)
    )

#   Title                Genres Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
# 1     A [Item1, Item2, Item3]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2     B                       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3     C        [Item4, Item1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```