# Split string into single letters and remember position

Tags: r, string, split

I have a dataset like this:

```
# test data
test.table <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1,3),
  sequence = c('HELLOTHISISASTRING','STRING|IS||18|LONG','SOMEOTHERSTRING!!!')
)
```

Each sequence has the same length (18). Now I want to create a table like this:

```
#id  position letter
#1   1        H
#1   2        E
#1   3        L
#.....etc
```

Although I know I can split the strings using `strsplit`, like so:

```
splitted <- strsplit(as.character(test.table$sequence), '')
```

I can't figure out how this should be converted to my preferred format?

Comment: May we ask why you need this output?

Comment: Sure! Obviously my real data doesn't look like these meaningless strings. I basically have two datasets. One like this, containing ids + strings and another one having the format id, position, positional characteristics. I need to join both datasets to obtain a table like: id position letter positional characteristic. Hopefully this make sense without going into my dataset too much @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(test.table$sequence), ""), test.table$id))`, [see also this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773770/2204410)

Comment: Do you need `l1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(test.table$sequence), '')); data.frame(position = seq_along(l1), letter = l1)` ?

Comment: @jaap This doesn't seem to show the letter positions

Comment: Just add rowid, e.g.: `res <- stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(test.table$sequence), ""), test.table$id)); res$rowID <- 1:18`

Comment: @CodeNoob It was indeed a starter, posted a complete answer below.

Comment: Based on your older questions, this is a bio data, right? Could you explain in bio context what we are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy package about operations like such called `splitstackshape`.

```
library(splitstackshape)

dt1 <- cSplit(test.table, 'sequence', sep = '', direction = 'long', stripWhite = FALSE)
dt1$pos <- seq(18)
```

which gives,

> ```
>     id sequence pos
>  1:  1        H   1
>  2:  1        E   2
>  3:  1        L   3
>  4:  1        L   4
>  5:  1        O   5
>  6:  1        T   6
>  7:  1        H   7
>  8:  1        I   8
>  9:  1        S   9
> 10:  1        I  10
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyverse` tools:

```r
test.table <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1,3),
  sequence = c('HELLOTHISISASTRING','STRING|IS||18|LONG','SOMEOTHERSTRING!!!')
)
library(tidyverse)

test.table %>%
  mutate(letters = str_split(sequence, "")) %>%
  unnest %>%
  group_by(id, sequence) %>%
  mutate(position = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 54 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, sequence [3]
#>       id sequence           letters position
#>    <int> <fct>              <chr>      <int>
#>  1     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING H              1
#>  2     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING E              2
#>  3     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING L              3
#>  4     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING L              4
#>  5     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING O              5
#>  6     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING T              6
#>  7     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING H              7
#>  8     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING I              8
#>  9     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING S              9
#> 10     1 HELLOTHISISASTRING I             10
#> # ... with 44 more rows
```

Created on 2018-09-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

```
df <- stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(test.table$sequence), ""), test.table$id))[2:1]
df$pos <- with(df, ave(values, ind, FUN = seq_along))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    ind values pos
> 1    1      H   1
> 2    1      E   2
> 3    1      L   3
> 4    1      L   4
> 5    1      O   5
> 6    1      T   6
> 7    1      H   7
> 8    1      I   8
> ....
> ```

---

Or using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test.table)

test.table[, .(letter = unlist(tstrsplit(sequence, "", fixed=TRUE))), id
           ][, pos := rowid(id)][]
```

which gives the same result:

> ```
>     id letter pos
>  1:  1      H   1
>  2:  1      E   2
>  3:  1      L   3
>  4:  1      L   4
>  5:  1      O   5
>  6:  1      T   6
>  7:  1      H   7
>  8:  1      I   8
> ....
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
data=data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(test.table)){ # For each id
 # Split the data for each index and store the itermediate result and 
 # bind it as id, position and letter
 df=cbind(test.table$id[i],1: stri_length(test.table$sequence[i]),stri_sub(test.table$sequence[i],
     seq(1, stri_length(test.table$sequence[i]),by=1), length=1))
 data=rbind(data,df) # Append each id result to data
} 
colnames(data)=c('id','position','letter')
```

Output:

```
  id position letter
1  1        1      H
2  1        2      E
3  1        3      L
4  1        4      L
5  1        5      O
6  1        6      T
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here already, but here is another way to do it using `tidyverse`.

```
test.table <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1,3),
  sequence = c('HELLOTHISISASTRING','STRING|IS||18|LONG','SOMEOTHERSTRING!!!')
)

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

test.table %>% 
  separate(col=sequence, into=as.character(1:18), sep=1:17) %>% 
  melt('id', value.name = 'letter', variable.name='position') %>% 
  arrange(id, position)
```

In the above code, the `separate` function from `tidyr` separates the `sequence` column into 18 separate columns (naming them 1 to 18) and then those are melted into the `letter` and `position` columns.

Comment: It's from `reshape2`, which apparently is not loaded with `tidyverse` - I added `library(reshape2)`. Thank you!

Comment: No need for reshape, tidyverse (tidyr package) has the `gather` function, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is not as per requirement, but guessing based on your comment, we might need this instead:

```
chartr("HES", "ZXY", test.table$sequence)
# [1] "ZXLLOTZIYIYAYTRING" "YTRING|IY||18|LONG" "YOMXOTZXRYTRING!!!"
```

Where we are replacing every H with Z, E with X, S with Y, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation on a theme.

```
library(tidyverse)

test.table %>% 
  nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(letters = map(data, ~str_split(.x$sequence,'') %>% unlist()),
         numbers = map(letters, ~1:length(.x))) %>%
  unnest(letters, numbers)
#> # A tibble: 54 x 3
#>       id letters numbers
#>    <int> <chr>     <int>
#>  1     1 H             1
#>  2     1 E             2
#>  3     1 L             3
#>  4     1 L             4
#>  5     1 O             5
#>  6     1 T             6
#>  7     1 H             7
#>  8     1 I             8
#>  9     1 S             9
#> 10     1 I            10
#> # ... with 44 more rows
```

or slightly different to avoid 2 calls to map

```
test.table %>% 
  nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(newdata = map(data, ~data_frame(
    letters = str_split(.x$sequence, "") %>% unlist(),
    numbers = 1:str_count(.x$sequence)))) %>%
  unnest(newdata)
#> # A tibble: 54 x 3
#>       id letters numbers
#>    <int> <chr>     <int>
#>  1     1 H             1
#>  2     1 E             2
#>  3     1 L             3
#>  4     1 L             4
#>  5     1 O             5
#>  6     1 T             6
#>  7     1 H             7
#>  8     1 I             8
#>  9     1 S             9
#> 10     1 I            10
#> # ... with 44 more rows
```

Created on 2018-09-07 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).