# Separate variables in same row, divided by ; acconding to another column in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and now I got a question regarding the dataframe which I am working with.

I have some columns with several answers from a survey. Below are two columns:

```
OperatingSystem    LanguageWorkedWith
Linux              C;C++;C#
Windows            Java; JavaScript
Mac                C
Linux              C#
```

And need to break it down into separated rows acconding to the OperatingSystem (also in 2 columns: OperatingSystem and LanguageWorkedWith):

```
Linux   C
Linux   C++
```

and so on... Sorry if the question is duplicated, I just couldn't find a solution for that.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows ?

Comment: Yes!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`separate_rows` in the tidyr package can do that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% separate_rows(LanguageWorkedWith, sep = ";")
```

giving:

```
  OperatingSystem LanguageWorkedWith
1           Linux                  C
2           Linux                C++
3           Linux                 C#
4         Windows               Java
5         Windows         JavaScript
6             Mac                  C
7           Linux                 C#
```

### Note

The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "OperatingSystem - LanguageWorkedWith
Linux - C;C++;C#
Windows - Java; JavaScript
Mac - C
Linux - C#"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "-", strip.white = TRUE, comment = "")
```