# R - from wide to long format using combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Assume I have the following database `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c("A", "B", "C"),
             Var1 = c(234, 12, 345),
             Var2 = c(4, 555, 325),
             Var3 = c("45|221|2", "982", NA))

> df
  ID Var1 Var2     Var3
1  A  234    4 45|221|2
2  B   12  555      982
3  C  345  325     <NA>
```

I would like to create a data.frame in which `Var1` and `Var2` is combined with the elements in `Var3` by `ID`.

The outcome I am looking for should look like the following:

```
> outcome
  ID VarA VarB
1  A  234   45
2  A  234  221
3  A  234    2
4  A    4   45
5  A    4  221
6  A    4    2
7  B   12  982
8  B  555  982
```

Note that:

- the elements in `Var3` are separated by a vertical bar `|`
- `ID == C` is not in `outcome` because `Var3` is `NA` for that `ID`.

The original data consists of millions of IDs.

Comment: This seems to be a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows in combination with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Comment: @markus Indeed, there are a bunch of entries on moving from wide to long, and how to split a character string. The tricky part here, I guess, is to properly stack Var1-Var3 and Var2-Var3 by ID, and to do this efficiently.

Comment: What about `library(tidyverse); df %>% filter(ID != "C") %>% separate_rows(Var3, sep = "\\|") %>% gather(key, Var2, -ID, -Var3) %>% select(-key) %>% arrange(ID)` ?

Comment: @markus I didn't see you wrote a similar answer to mine until posting refreshed the page. If you want to post yours, I'll remove mine, as I think `separate_rows` is a more logical function to use for this problem, even though `str_split` and `unnest` have the same result.

Comment: @Mako212 Don't worry. Edit your answer and include `separate_rows` if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` for a fairly elegant solution. The general idea is that we can use `separate_rows` to expand `Var3` into rows, we just need to get `Var1/Var2` into a suitable long format so we don't unnecessarily duplicate values.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>% gather(variable, value, -ID, -Var3) %>% # pull Var1 and Var2 into 
  # a single pair of key/value columns
  separate_rows(Var3, sep = "\\|") %>% # split Var3 into rows for each value
  drop_na(Var3) %>% # drop the NA rows
  select(ID, VarA = value, VarB = Var3, -variable) %>%
  arrange(ID)

  ID VarA VarB
1  A  234   45
2  A  234  221
3  A  234    2
4  A    4   45
5  A    4  221
6  A    4    2
7  B   12  982
8  B  555  982
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` and `splitstackshape` you can do:

```
df %>%
 filter(!is.na(Var3)) %>%
 select(-Var3) %>%
 gather(var, VarA, -ID) %>%
 select(-var) %>%
 full_join(df %>%
            filter(!is.na(Var3)) %>%
            cSplit("Var3", sep = "|") %>%
            select(-Var1, -Var2) %>%
            gather(var, VarB, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            select(-var), by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>%
 arrange(ID, VarA, VarB)

  ID VarA VarB
1  A    4    2
2  A    4   45
3  A    4  221
4  A  234    2
5  A  234   45
6  A  234  221
7  B   12  982
8  B  555  982
```

First, it filters out the rows where there is a NA on "Var3". Second it transforms the data from wide to long format, without the variable "Var3". Finally, it performs a full join with the df where the rows with NA on "Var3" were filtered out and "Var3" was split based on "|" and then transformed to wide to long format, without "Var1" and "Var2".