# Convert comma separated column into multiple columns

Tags: r, string, split, strsplit

I have a dataset of film with several columns, one of which is a column for country. Because some films are produced by more than one country, the film can have different countries at the same time in the "country" column. For example, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsEOH.png)

I now want to create a new dataset in which each row in “country” column can only has one country. For example, in the screenshot above, *Bluebeard* are produced by “France”, “Germany”, and “Italy” country. Right now, I want the dataset showing that *Bluebeard* is produced by “France”, “Germany”, and “Italy” country separately.

I tried strsplit()and colsplit() function, but that doesn’t seem to convert comma-separated "country" column into multiple columns that only contain one country each row.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows) for help?

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr`:

```
separate_rows(data, country, sep = ", ")
```