# Regex replace within list in r column

Tags: r, regex, replace

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1  COL2
G1    [OK_+__SP2,PL_-__SP2]
G2    [IQO_-__SP1_8,PL2_-__SP2]
G2    [IRO_+__SP8]
```

and I would like to remove **for each element** of the `COL2`, the part before `__`

and get

```
COL1  COL2
G1    ['SP2','SP2']
G2    ['SP1_8','SP2']
G2    ['SP8']
```

Comment: Does it always start with "SP"?

Comment: no it can be any ohter name..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So this post is a duplicate of Regex FAQ post? By that logic every regex post could be closed with that FAQ post, no? Maybe provide link to exact duplicate target post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `str_remove_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(COL2 = str_remove_all(COL2, "[^\\[,]+__"))
```

-output

```
#   COL1        COL2
#1   G1   [SP2,SP2]
#2   G2 [SP1_8,SP2]
#3   G2       [SP8]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COL1 = c("G1", "G2", "G2"), COL2 = c("[OK_+__SP2,PL_-__SP2]", 
"[IQO_-__SP1_8,PL2_-__SP2]", "[IRO_+__SP8]")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gsub("(?<=[\\[,])(.*?__)", "", df1$COL2, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "[SP2,SP2]"   "[SP1_8,SP2]" "[SP8]"
```

Remove between:

- `(?<=[\\[,])` look behind, check if it is `[` or `,`
- `(.*?__)` up to, including `__`

**Note:** not great with regex, probably there are better ways.

Comment: thanks, and how can I now transform the COL2 into list that I can iterate within each row ?

Comment: @chippycentra do you need to have those square brackets at all?

Comment: @chippycentra see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773770/680068) regarding delimited string into new rows.