# Merge two dataframes by several columns (with sub element in columns) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Hello everyone I would need help in order to merge two dataframe.

So I have a dataframe such as

**df1**

```
                               SP_names              Groups  Number
1 Canis_lupus,Homo_sapiens,Mus_musculus   3_Group2,5_Group8 Number1
2             Canis_lupus,Cattus_cattus 6_Group37,8_Group89 Number2
3                        Apis_mellifera          1_Group673 Number3
```

and

**df2**

```
     SP_names     Groups
1    Canis_lupus   3_Group2
2    Canis_lupus   5_Group8
3   Homo_sapiens   5_Group8
4    Canis_lupus  6_Group37
5   Mus_musculus   3_Group2
6  Cattus_cattus  6_Group37
7  Cattus_cattus   8_Group89
8 Apis_mellifera 1_Group673
```

and the idea is to add into **df2** the column `Number` from **df1** by groupping `Groups` and `SP_names`.

The difficulty is that within `df1$Groups` and `df1$SP_names` I can have mutliple values separated by a `,`.

So the **expected output** would be :

```
        SP_names     Groups Number
1    Canis_lupus   3_Group2 Number1
2    Canis_lupus   5_Group8 Number1
3   Homo_sapiens   5_Group8 Number1
4    Canis_lupus  6_Group37 Number2
5   Mus_musculus   3_Group2 Number1
6  Cattus_cattus  6_Group37 Number2
7  Cattus_cattus   _Group89 Number2
8 Apis_mellifera 1_Group673 Number3
```

where for instance Canis lupuse was present in `df1$Number` `Number1` and `Number2`, si I juste checked the match between `df1$Groups/df2$Groups` and `df1$SP_names/df2$SP_names`to assign the Number value in the right place in df2.

Does someone have an idea please

Here are the data

**df1**

```
structure(list(SP_names = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Apis_mellifera", 
"Canis_lupus,Cattus_cattus", "Canis_lupus,Homo_sapiens,Mus_musculus"
), class = "factor"), Groups = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1_Group673", 
"3_Group2,5_Group8", "6_Group37,8_Group89"), class = "factor"), 
    Number = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Number1", "Number2", 
    "Number3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(SP_names = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("Apis_mellifera", "Canis_lupus", "Cattus_cattus", 
"Homo_sapiens", "Mus_musculus"), class = "factor"), Groups = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1_Group673", "3_Group2", 
"5_Group8", "6_Group37", "8_Group89"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Seems like you may start here to tidy your data: [Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows), then a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work.. but what about row 7 from you output?
`_Group89` does nog exist in df1. typo?

```
library( tidyverse )
df1_long <- df1 %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows( SP_names, sep = "," ) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows( Groups, sep = "," )

df2 %>% dplyr::left_join( df1_long )
```

Comment: Yes there were a typo ahah, thank you very much it seems to work fine ! :-)