# How to check for string matches in data.table in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table

```
library(data.table)
tab1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1, 2, 100, 100),
                   class = c(2, 2, 1, 5),
                   number = c(96, 100, 55, 55),
                   code1 = c("123", "125", "999", "999"))
tab2 <- data.table(id2 = c(100, 200, 200, 205, 205, 205),
                   class = c(2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2),
                   max_number = c(100, 80, 80, 95, 95, 95),
                   min_number = c(0, 50, 50, 10, 10, 10),
                   code2 = c("123,999", "100,105", "100,105", "555,999", "234,999", "123,999,555"))

> tab1
   id1 class number code1
1:   1     2     96   123
2:   2     2    100   125
3: 100     1     55   999
4: 100     5     55   999
> tab2
   id2 class max_number min_number       code2
1: 100     2        100          0     123,999
2: 200     2         80         50     100,105
3: 200     1         80         50     100,105
4: 205     5         95         10     555,999
5: 205     2         95         10     234,999
6: 205     2         95         10 123,999,555
```

I have two tables. For each `id1`, I would like to match on `class`, `min_number <= number <= max_number` and see if `code1` matches anything (partially) in `code2`. That is, "123" would be a match for "123, 999, 555".

My attempt is below. The column `V1` contains the `id2`s that matched.

```
> tab2[tab1, on = c("class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(list(id2)), by = .EACHI]
   class max_number min_number  V1
1:     2         96         96 100
2:     2        100        100 100
3:     1         55         55 200
4:     5         55         55 205
```

Just matching on `class` and `min_number <= number <= max_number` works fine. But trying to do the partial string match with `grepl` gives the following error:

```
> tab2[tab1, on = c("class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number", grepl("code2", "code1")), .(list(id2)), by = .EACHI]
Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[4]='FALSE'
```

The desired output is something like this (where `V1` contains the `id2`s that matches each row in `tab1`):

```
   id1 class max_number min_number      V1
1:   1     2         96         96     100
2:   2     2        100        100    <NA>
3: 100     1         55         55    <NA>
4: 100     5         55         55 205,205
```

Comment: I think you make your life easier by casting your data to a tidy, long format before joining. See e.g. [Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514711/1851712). If desired, you can re-concatenate the values in a last step, e.g. for reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `grepl` in the join condition, but you could calculate it using `mapply`:

```
tab2[tab1, on = c("class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(code1,code2,id1,id2,select = mapply(grepl,code1,code2)), by = .EACHI][
     ,.(list(fifelse(select,id2,NA))),by=.(id1,class,max_number,min_number)]

     id1 class max_number min_number     V1
   <num> <num>      <num>      <num> <list>
1:     1     2         96         96    100
2:     2     2        100        100     NA
3:   100     1         55         55     NA
4:   100     5         55         55    205
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use `grepl` to match on multiple columns? For example, I want to do `select = c(mapply(grepl, code1, code2), mapply(grepl, class1, class2))` where `class1` is the `class` column in `tab1`, and `class2` in `tab2`?

Comment: as `mapply` returns an arry of logical, you can combine two arrays with the `&` operator:`mapply(grepl,code1,code2)&mapply(grepl,class1,class2)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably I have to use `strsplit` instead of `grepl` here

```
tab2[,
  .(code2 = unlist(strsplit(code2, ","))),
  by = id2:min_number
][
  tab1, 
  .(id1, class, min_number, max_number, id2),
  on = c("class", "min_number <= number", "max_number >= number", "code2 == code1")
]
```

which gives

```
   id1 class min_number max_number id2
1:   1     2         96         96 100
2:   2     2        100        100  NA
3: 100     1         55         55  NA
4: 100     5         55         55 205
```