# Dplyr: Rearrange a Dataframe by Putting Multiple Factors in One Cell in Multiple Columns into Separate Individual Rows into one Column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

**Overview**

I have a data frame with 444 rows and 361 columns. In 3 of the columns named **'Collaborations', 'Mini Collaborations', and 'Subcontractors'**, I've inputted multiple factors showing the names of collaborators, all inputted into one cell separated by commas. Some cells can contain up to 30 names.

**Aim:**

My ultimate aim is to rearrange the data frame by manipulating the factors (separated by a comma) in every single cell **(see Table 1 - column titles'Collaborations', 'Mini Collaborations', and 'Subcontractors')**, and place all the information from all three columns them into individual separate rows **(see Table 2)** in one single column called **'Collaborations'**.

**Problem:**

In some single cells, there are no names, just the value zero, and, I don't want to output multiple rows within the new column **'Collaborations'** with zeros.

In the future, I want to be able to filter the new data frame that's been outputted by each collaborator's name to track the dates they've worked and their work history.

I apologise for not providing a sample code, but I'm not an expert with R. I can use **dplyr** and **data.table**, but
I've tried hard to find a way and I've been unsuccessful.

This question [Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows) was flagged up to me, and it was very helpful in rearranging one column using this code:

```
Df %>% mutate(Collaborations = strsplit(as.character(Collaborations), ",")) %>% unnest(Collaborations)
```

However, I'm not sure how to rearrange three columns this way, put them into one column, and, delete the columns that contain zeros so they are not duplicated into the new column **'Collaborators'**.

I've provided a sample data frame below. If anyone can help, I'd be appreciative.

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

**Dataframe**

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L), levels = c("1/1/23", 
"10/1/23", "2/1/23", "4/1/23", "6/1/23", "8/1/23"), class = "factor"), 
    Start_Time = structure(c(6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("4:30", 
    "5:13", "7:30", "8:25", "8:45", "9:10"), class = "factor"), 
    End_Time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L), levels = c("12:30", 
    "14:15", "14:20", "15:25", "16:17", "18:17"), class = "factor"), 
    Project = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("Business_Ltd", 
    "Clyde_Ltd", "Fabian_Ltd", "Friends_Ltd", "Greenhouse_Ltd", 
    "Red_Ltd"), class = "factor"), Collaborations = structure(c(2L, 
    6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L), levels = c("FRANK, TESSA", "JON, SAM, LEAH", 
    "LEO, TIA", "LOUISE, TINA", "PATTY, JOAN", "PIERRE, LESLEY"
    ), class = "factor"), Mini_Collborations = structure(c(3L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), levels = c("0", "GEORGE", "MEL", "TILLY", 
    "TONY, JIM"), class = "factor"), Subcontractors = structure(c(5L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L), levels = c("0", "CHAN, BEN", "KIM, UNA", 
    "KIRK, TRACY, KELLY", "SKYLER, TEESCHA"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to transform your data into long format and remove the "0" entries:

```
df |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(Collaborations, Mini_Collborations, Subcontractors),
                 names_to = "Role",
                 values_to = "Collaborations") |> 
    separate_rows(Collaborations, sep = ", ") |> 
    select(-Role) |> 
    filter(Collaborations != "0")
```

Note that I'm using the native pipe operator `|>`, but `%>%` will work equally.

Comment: Thanks, Ramell, this worked perfectly. You're a legend